# How to Prevent some model attributes from Update?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, attributes, model-binding

I'm using Scaffolding in ASP.Net, I've a Model called "Page" which has attributes as follows

```
public class Page
{
    private DateTime _Created_at = DateTime.Now;
    private bool _IsActive = true;

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Parent Code")]
    public string ParentCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    ************
}
```

Here, During **Create** Method, I'm updating Code attributes as follows

```
        public ActionResult Create(Page page)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                page.Code = page.Url.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                page.IsActive = true;
                db.Pages.Add(page);

                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = page.ID });
            }

            return View(page);
        }
```

Now, Problem is, I don't want this **Code** value change during **Update** method, I'm not included it in Edit form. But still it's updating 'NULL' value if I update.

I tried `[Bind(Exclude = "Code")]` for Page class, But no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a hidden field for `code` in your edit view. Use `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Code)`.

Comment: Thanks dude, It's working. I need to know one more thing, why [Bind(Exclude = "Code")] this is not working? how to use this? Is hiddenFor is the only option for this?

Comment: No Dude, There is no Input field for `code` both in `Create` and `Edit` form

Comment: Without this field, your view will not have any idea what value your `code` had. Add this field and then you will not get a `null` for code in the posted `page`. I have never used `[Bind(Exclude = "...")]`. But If you are using it properly, I hope it will work now.

Comment: By removing `[Bind(Exclude = "...")]` and by adding `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Code)` my Problem is solved. But I'm not not getting the myth of it. Any way, problem is solved. Thanks for your help...

Comment: By having `HiddenFor` you are effectively telling the framework that the field is part of the view layout, and it needs to stay hidden, so its value won't change. However, if you don't put `HiddenFor`, `TextFor`, `EditorFor` etc, basically not using it, its value will become `null` since you using entire view model but not this field, so it doesn't get initialized with anything meaningful. I know, its counter intuitive, but when you know how framework works, it makes sense. Good luck